# Mcrypt PHP extension required

Tags: xampp, laravel-4

lo que me sucede es que tengo que trabajar en un proyecto que se encuentra el laravel4.2 y mi xammp tiene php 7.2.3 y cuando trato de correr el proyecto me aparece el error Mcrypt PHP extension required. eh intentado cambiar la version de Xammp pero el error persiste

Comment: tengo el mismo problema, pero mi Xampp, no tiene el archivo "php.ini", que puedo hacer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes revisar en XAMPP el archivo php.ini donde deberás ubicar los siguientes 2 archivos(si es que existen)

```
;extension=php_mcrypt.dll
;extension=php_mcrypt_filter.dll
```

Como notas tienen punto y coma al inicio lo cual indica que estan deshabilitados; por lo tanto deberás quitarle dichos simbolos para que queden como a continuación

```
extension=php_mcrypt.dll
extension=php_mcrypt_filter.dll
```

> Una vez que hagas dichos cambios, guarda tu archivo php.ini y reinicia
>   XAMPP

Ahora entiendo que dices estar trabajando sobre un proyecto ya hecho

> en dicha versión, pero considera los pros y contras pues esa versión
>   ya no recibe soporte

Comment: muchas gracias, me sirvio su explicacion , Saludos